# What are some differences between Router and Endpoint and URL?

Tags: rest, api, frontend, alamofire, backend

I'm building network layer for calling APIs on FrontEnd to Backend. There are concepts (Router, Endpoint and URL) which really confuse me. Can someone help me and explain what are some differences between Router, Endpoint and URL? It would be nice if I can have some code (small class, structure) example then I can easy understand.

Answer (score 1):

Router: receives calls and forwards them to the a specific endpoint depending on the path

Endpoint: each of the URL or methods that can be accessed

URL: path to a specific endpoint